# ArrayField consisting of composite field type

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have modeled composite field using https://pypi.org/project/django-composite-field/ in my django model (A URL field + a Boolean Field). What I want is to store a number of those (maybe in a list) in my base 'User' model. But ArrayField using `django.contrib.postgres.fields` only support a single data type. What I want is a list of the object (URL + boolean) for every user. Further I want to add validations for the number of objects eg.(min 2 objects, max 6 objects). What is a good way to model this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you better use separate table and ForeignKey. Judging by the description of these composite fields, this is just a wrapper over several model fields. Unnecessary complexity for you

Comment: I did think of that, creating a model having user Id as foreign key, image URL and displayPicture Boolean. But how will I  validate that number of these objects are inside a range?